# Can't block android.permission.INTERNET on specific Application using Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise, emm

I need to block network access to specific applications using Android management API.

I tried creating a policy something like that:

```
{
"applications": [
{
  "packageName": "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
  "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
  "permissionGrants": [
    {
      "permission": "android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE",
      "policy": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "permission": "android.permission.INTERNET",
      "policy": "DENY"
    }
  ]
}
]}
```

However it doesn't work, when checking the device's non-compliance details I'm getting this:

```
{
"nonComplianceDetails": [
        {
          "settingName": "applications",
          "nonComplianceReason": "API_LEVEL",
          "packageName": "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
          "fieldPath": "applications[1].permissionGrants"
        },
      ],
}
```

Which basically means that my version of android doesn't support this restriction, I tried it on API 30 & 31.

I can't find any documentation on blocking network access to applications, and on which API level it's supported, anyone with experience on that?

Answer (score 2):

With Android Management API [Resource:Policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#resource:-policy) [PermissionGrant](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#permissiongrant) is used for runtime (dangerous) permissions. Both [Internet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INTERNET) and [CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE) permissions are [normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous), meaning they're granted at install time and don't need to be requested at runtime. More than likely, this is the reason your policy is triggering non-compliance.

One potential solution to block this application from the internet is to require a VPN connection (that does not route to the internet) for this application.

Answer (score 0):

android.permission.INTERNET is a special permission which cannot be granted or denied